# Would this 'guide' be considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I saw [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/339214/88313) and answer from the same person.

It appears the OP wanted to post a 'guide' to users making the change from PC to Mac.  Is a guide the proper question for a Q&A site?

Perhaps if the OP edited the question to focus on a specific keyboard issue or shortcut then I wouldn't have an issue with the question.  This looks more like a 'how to' disguised as a question and answer but I wanted to run this past others to see if I'm viewing this question incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posts like that are always a bit tricky, and we probably would need a broader discussion if we have a significant increase in that kind of Q&A posted on the side. For just one such post now and then the focus should be on the post itself.

The question itself shows the usual signs of a question written after the answer was already clear, which makes it a bit hard to understand without also looking at the answer. But I‘ve Seen similar Q&A posts which have been much worse, the one here primarily needs a bit polishing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure on the correct protocol but in my opinion "How to"/Guide questions are good and should be allowed.  While it doesn't fit the Q&A style per se, the question could be asked in a way prompting the Guide response.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer!  I would disagree on this.  I think there's plenty of 'how-to' sites, like Medium, that are better designed for that sort of thing.  I look at the SE sites as excellent QA sites; I have a problem and I know where to go to get a fix.  While how-to's are very useful at times, it doesn't really fit the SE format.

Comment: @fsb While many other sites have good guides, I don't think most of them benefit from a community who can edit, vote, check, update, etc. the post to make sure it works and is accurate. I do think more people would agree with you on this though. :)